# Django reverse ForeignKey lookup returns None

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I'm new to Django development and have just started writing an app.
I have two classes defined in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NEO(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=' ')
    sighter     = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    date_sighted    = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    ratings     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #coords     = models.ForeignKey('Coords', default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Coords(models.Model):
    ra      = models.FloatField('Right Ascension', default=0)
    dec     = models.FloatField('Declination', default=0)
    neo     = models.ForeignKey(NEO, related_name='neo_coords', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.ra) + ' ' + str(self.dec)
```

Each `Coords` object links to a single `NEO` and vice versa. 
Uncommenting the `Neo.Coords` line and then calling `n.Coords` returns a `None`. Given a `NEO` object, how can I get the corresponding `Coords` object?

Comment: One question: should I be using a OneToOne?

Comment: Yes, if One `neo` object can have a relation with only one `coords` object.

Answer (score 4):

ForeignKey here is a ManyToOne relationship ([as suggested in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)), So in your case multiple `Coords` objects can be binded to a single `NEO` object. If you want a OneToOne Relation you may want to use `models.OneToOneField` ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)).

In case of foreign key's lookup you can use.

```
NEO.coords_set.get(**lookup_arguments_here)
# Here NEO.coords_set is the list of coords objects bound to this particular NEO object.
```

and in case of `OneToOne` you can simply use

```
NEO.coords
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have two tables referencing each other with dual foreign keys because you run into a chicken or the egg problem. You need to decide whether or not there can be a one-to-many relation or a one-to-one relation.

Can a `NEO` have multiple `Coords`? Can a `Coord` have multiple `NEOs`? If the answer is yes, then you need a `ForeignKey`. The `ForeignKey` should be on the many of the `one-to-many` side of the relation. If the answer was no, and there can only be a one-to-one link, then you want a `OneToOneField`.

To access the [reverse side of the relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) it is simple:

```
# multiple coords per neo

class NEO(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Coords(models.Model):
    name = ...
    neo = models.ForeignKey(NEO)

c = Coords.objects.get(id=1)
c.neo # shows the neo

n = NEO.objects.get(id=1)
coords = n.coords_set.all() # multiple coords per neo
```

If instead you had a one to one relationship:

```
class NEO(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Coords(models.Model):
    name = ...
    neo = models.OneToOneField(NEO)

c = Coords.objects.get(id=1)
c.neo # shows the neo

n = NEO.objects.get(id=1)
coords = n.coords # only one possible coord per neo
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Trying n.coords returns "AttributeError: 'NEO' object has no attribute 'coords'".